# What's a C++03 compliant way of fetching a value from a volatile variable?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

According to this [defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1054) C++03 Standard does not guarantee that in the following code:

```
volatile int x;
void f() {
    x;
}
```

the variable is read from.

Then how do I write code that just read the volatile variable value and discards the result (read for the sake of read)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @AndreasBrinck I don't know why the OP would want this specifically, but it's pretty common in embedded programming, where you might want to read from a memory-mapped register, and that read can cause some side effect to happen.

Comment: @Andreas Brinck: This is needed to enforce the operating system to actually allocate a memory page - the allocation is delayed until the first access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int i = x;` should work. This code absolutely requires reading the volatile variable and the optimizer is not allowed to optimize the read away. But since the variable `i` is unused the optimizer can avoid any extra work involved in storing the read value.

You might also need something like this to avoid compiler warnings: `(void)i;`